# Dell Laptop BIOS Flash Without Boot Menu

Tags: bios, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 7590 (running Ubuntu) that I am trying to get mining. When I got it to charge one time, I tried updating it's BIOS to the latest version. It unintentionally shut down in the middle of the update, and now I am stuck with a *lovely* BIOS recovery screen, that, when I get the computer charged enough, does not work. I have tried removing the battery and RTC, to no avail. Is there some Dell version of Qflash Plus that I don't know about? Or will I just have to accept my loss and salvage the SSD for my planned PC build?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the boot menu by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> during POST. There will be an option to
flash the BIOS for an update. This utility will also parse and use the .EXE file from the Dell downloads site for the BIOS update.